# Request to a downlevel service failed

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to create a Service Bus Namespace using the [REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj856303.aspx). Below is my code:

```
var uri = string.Format("https://management.core.windows.net/{0}/services/ServiceBus/Namespaces/{1}", subscriptionId, sericebusToCreate);    
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "PUT";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2014-10-01");

var requestContent = @"<NamespaceDescription xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
<Name>" + sericebusToCreate + @"</Name>
<Region>Southeast Asia</Region><ServiceBusEndpoint>https://configpoc.servicebus.windows.net/</ServiceBusEndpoint>                      <SubscriptionId>My-subscription</SubscriptionId><Critical>false</Critical>              <EventHubEnabled>true</EventHubEnabled>     <NamespaceType>Messaging</NamespaceType></NamespaceDescription>";
var requestBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(requestContent);
request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
request.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

try
{                
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
//Do something with response
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
var err = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(err);
}
```

For getting authentication token, I am using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx) method. I can confirm that this method works since I am able to use other REST APIs such as Get Namespace etc.

When I execute the code, I get "Request to a downlevel service failed" error.

I got very little help from google. It seems like very few people have faced this issue. Can anyone explain me what is causing this issue and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I could never figure out the reason for this error, I did find another way to create service bus using [Azure Service Bus Management APIs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus/). It is much simpler to use and works as expected.

***One must note that this library is as of now in "Pre-Release" version.***